# Getting HTML code from website to setText on EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

I have had many errors and while searching around I have received many different solutions that confused me and thus I man making this post to search for one final answer. So as the title states, I am trying to make my app get the HTML code of the website link that I feed it and will then sniff out information from that to set into my EditText. I have tried searching around, and a solution I received and changed a little was to use this Utility class

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.MalformedURLException
import java.net.URL

object ContentScrapper {


    fun getHTMLData(activity: AppCompatActivity,url: String, scrapListener: ScrapListener) {
        Thread(Runnable {

            val google: URL?
            val `in`: BufferedReader?
            var input: String?
            val stringBuffer = StringBuffer()

            try {
                google = URL(url)
                `in` = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(google.openStream()))
                while (true) {
                    if (`in`.readLine().also { input = it } == null)
                        break
                    stringBuffer.append(input)
                }
                `in`.close()

                activity.runOnUiThread {
                    scrapListener.onResponse(stringBuffer.toString())
                }
            } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                activity.runOnUiThread {
                    scrapListener.onResponse(null)
                }
            }
        }).start()

    }


    interface ScrapListener {
        fun onResponse(html: String?)
    }
}
```

Like this in my Main Activity

```
ContentScrapper.getHTMLData(this,"http://google.com/",object : ContentScrapper.ScrapListener{
            override fun onResponse(html: String?) {
                if(html != null) {
                    editTexttest.setText(html)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity,"Not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        })
```

And I did, but initialising the EditText like this so seemed to return a null error

```
val testingbox: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTexttest)
```

So I looked around and found that I didn't need to initialise and I could just do editTexttest.setText?

But then I received these errors

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onResponse(MainActivity.kt:41)
        at com.example.myapplication.ContentScrapper$getHTMLData$1$2.run(Util.kt:31)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Line 41 was the editTexttest.setText and line 31 was scrapListener.onResponse(stringBuffer.toString()).

If anyone could explain what is wrong that would be great. Thanks.

EDIT: I tunnel visioned and was looking at the wrong activity the entire time. Dumb mistake on my part.

Comment: show us your corresponding .xml file.activity_main.xml file.

Comment: either the ID is not correct, or you are calling `findViewById(R.id.editTexttest)` too early (i.e. before the view was set).